# How to play DLC if game is finished?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Can I play the DLC from the point where I completed the main game story-line, or do I have to back up to some save-game that I created before I entered the final battle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is** another solution, check out [this mod](http://www.newvegasnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=40373). It worked when I tried it, it's worth a shot.

Simply download it, and place it in your `Data` folder where you installed Fallout NV, e.g `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\fallout new vegas\Data`. Then start the game laucher, and tick of the mod in `DATA FILES`.

Comment: Great find, works as advertised!

Answer (score 3):

You have to back up to a save prior to the end of the game. Unlike Broken Steel in Fallout 3, to play the DLC such as Honest Hearts and Dead Money, you have to do it during the game.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall reading somewhere recently that in a recent patch, a provision was made that creates a save right before the last battle that allows you to load and play the DLC before actually engaging in the battle.  I believe this patch was for all platforms.